# Group By View Ordering

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, calculated-column, grouping

Scenario: Created a list library and want to group by choices in look-up column titled Compass (North, West, South, East).  I want to put the choices in order but not in alphabetical order.

Problem: When you group you can only have it in descending or ascending order by the beginning letter of the group by options.  But I want to order by another column.

Has anyone found a solution before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rename ENSW  to 1-North, 2-South, 3-East, 4-West